# Which organs can be donated after clinical death?

Tags: medicine, organs, transplantation

The information I found about organ donation does not address clinical death. For example:

> The process of donation takes place only after physicians declare a
>   person **brain** dead [...] cessation of brain function [...] is
>   irreversible. However, the vital organs (heart, lungs, liver,
>   pancreas, intestine and kidneys) can be kept viable for a few days, if supported by artificial mechanical means (i.e. a ventilator).
>   ([source](http://www.dcids.org/facts-about-donation/frequently-asked-questions/))

However:

> Blood circulation can be stopped in the entire body below the heart
>   for at least 30 minutes, with injury to the spinal cord being a
>   limiting factor. Detached limbs may be successfully reattached after 6
>   hours of no blood circulation at warm temperatures. Bone, tendon, and
>   skin can survive as long as 8 to 12 hours. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_death#Limits_of_reversal))

Assuming the organs were not damaged by the cause of death itself, are there any organs that can be transplanted after **clinical** death?

Comment: It depends on why the patient died, and how long they were dead before the opportunity arises to harvest the organs. If you want to modify the question to narrow the scope, it is answerable. Death from a head injury on the highway or in the home - without any other significant injuries - provides the maximum potential for organ donation, with time being a critical component.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I'm actually interested in an answer covering the parameters you mentioned, assuming the organs were not damaged by the cause of death itself.

Comment: As the question stands, I think it might be too broad.